# Filter array during publication

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a document that looks as follows.

```
{
  _id: "1234",
  orderIds: [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

I want to publish this document, however, I want to lookup and filter this reactively. With an aggregation in 3.2, it would be something like this:

```
var id = "1234"
db.users.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: id } },
  { $unwind: '$orderIds' },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'orders', 
      as: 'orders',
      localField: 'orderIds',
      foreignField: '_id'
    }
  },
  { $match: { 'orders.status': { $ne: 'closed' } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      orders: { $push: '$orders' }
    }
  }
])
```

However, I can't find a way to do this with plain publications, and mongo 2.6.7 that meteor ships with. Is there a way to do it?